# Need perform aggregation operartion in pysaprk streaming job

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, azure-iot-hub

I'm receiving data of multiple sensors in stream in every 1 minute interval into databricks. Need to create a new sensor name 'PQRS' if sensors 'ABC' and 'DEF' is available for each pyspark streaming load and the value of the sensor should average of value of ABC and DEF.

`Input data(1 min stream)`

| sensor_name | value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| DEF | 20 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| GHI | 12 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |

Output data

| sensor_name | value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 10 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| DEF | 20 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| PQRS | 15 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| GHI | 12 | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |

Answer (score 0):

After receiving the streaming data into a dataframe, use the below code to achieve your requirement.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


#take the distinct count of timestamp column on the filter
time_count = input_stream.filter((input_stream.sensor_name == "ABC") | (input_stream.sensor_name == "DEF")).select("timestamp").distinct().count()

if time_count==1:
    temp_df= input_stream.filter((input_stream.sensor_name == "ABC") | (input_stream.sensor_name == "DEF")).groupBy("timestamp").agg(avg("value").alias("avg_value"))
    pqrs_df = temp_df.withColumn("sensor_name", lit("PQRS"))

    input_stream = input_stream.union(pqrs_df.select("sensor_name", "avg_value", "timestamp"))

#if its not distinct aggregation code won't be executed and new sensor will not be inserted
display(input_stream)
```

First it will calculate the distinct timestamp on the filter and if its 1 then next code will be executed.

In that, this will filter the rows which have `ABC` and `DEF` as `sensor_name` and calculates the average of `value`.

Then, create a new dataframe to add the `PQRS` sensor row and union that with your streaming dataframe and store the result into same dataframe. You can write this dataframe to your sink as per your requirement.

**Output for the above code:**

```
| sensor_name | value | timestamp                |
|-------------|-------|--------------------------|
| ABC         | 10    | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| DEF         | 20    | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| GHI         | 12    | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
| PQRS        | 15    | 2023-11-02T11:49:32.028Z |
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the case to be solved is do aggregation if both ABC and DEF is available for same timestamp, else no aggregation

Comment: I have edited my code. please check that.

Comment: Run the above code in databrick : `AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
tahoe`
Hit with above error

Comment: Check your streaming code. To do the transformations the above code will work.